# Not Able to Run Cassandra on AWS Ubuntu Instance

Tags: java, apache, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, cassandra-2.0

I'm having openJDK 1.7 version and Have installed Cassandra 2.1.8.
I have changed the CLASSPATH of CASSANDRA_HOME as well but I'm getting following error.

```
> root@ip-172-31-57-69:/usr/local/apache-cassandra/bin# export CASSANDRA_HOME=/usr/local/apache-cassandra/
root@ip-172-31-57-69:/usr/local/apache-cassandra/bin#  echo $CASSANDRA_HOME;
/usr/local/apache-cassandra/
root@ip-172-31-57-69:/usr/local/apache-cassandra/bin# cd /usr/local/apache-cassandra/
root@ip-172-31-57-69:/usr/local/apache-cassandra# bin/cassandra
root@ip-172-31-57-69:/usr/local/apache-cassandra# 
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/db/AbstractNativeCell.compareTo (Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/composites/Composite;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/db/composites/AbstractSimpleCellNameType.compareUnsigned (Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/composites/Composite;Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/composites/Composite;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/Memory.checkBounds (JJ)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/SafeMemory.checkBounds (JJ)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compare (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;[B)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compare ([BLjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compareUnsigned (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/lang/Object;JILjava/lang/Object;JI)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/lang/Object;JILjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon
```

Any help will be appreciated. I have been stuck in this for past 2 days.

Comment: If you have been stuck in this, maybe you can consider DataStax AMI? http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/introducing-the-datastax-auto-clustering-ami-2-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: set java home env variable 
[image]

2:set python path : C:\Python27
3: If other Python installed move this up.

Answer (score 0):

Install Java JDK then try running Cassandra.